# Listener in JavaScript Target not Executed

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I've created a grammar and generated the appropriate JavaScript target files with IntelliJ.

The parsing process seems to be working fine, because I get errors (or no errors) due to the attached error listener.

But I can't get my custom listener up and running. I want to transform the language to another one but the listener is ignored:

```
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(this.test);
var lexer = new dnpMDLexer.dnpMDLexer(chars);
var tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new dnpMDParser.dnpMDParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTrees = true;
parser.removeErrorListeners();
var errors = [];
var errorListener = new ErrorListener(errors);
parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);

var tree = parser.dnpMD();
var listener = new DnpMDListener();
antlr4.tree.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, tree);
```

And here's the code for the listener (just some functions implemented right now):

```
var dnpMDParserListener = require('./lib/dnpMD/dnpMDParserListener.js').dnpMDParserListener;

var DnpMDListener = function() {
    dnpMDParserListener.call(this);
    return this;
};

DnpMDListener.prototype = Object.create(dnpMDParserListener.prototype);
DnpMDListener.prototype.constructor = DnpMDListener;

DnpMDListener.prototype.enterDnpMD = function(ctx) {
    console.log("dnp: " + ctx);
}

DnpMDListener.prototype.enterHead = function(ctx) {
    console.log("Head: " + ctx);
}

DnpMDListener.prototype.enterHeadline = function(ctx) {
    console.log("Headline: " + ctx);
}
```

What am I missing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I just hadn't generated the Listener but though I did (the visitor was generated only).

And there the line:

```
var dnpMDParserListener = require('./dnpMDParserListener').dnpMDParserListener;
```

was missing including all necessary calls to the base listener.

Works perfectly well now.